# How to create zipcode boundaries in R

Tags: r, dictionary, zip, boundary

I am trying to create a map that has the name of the 'community' showing the boundaries of multiple zip codes. Data that I have is similar to below. Where the variable is the name of the community and the numbers are the corresponding zipcodes.

```
Tooele       <- c('84074','84029')
NEUtahCo     <- c('84003', '84004', '84042', '84062')
NWUtahCounty <- c('84005','84013','84043','84045')
```

I was able to make a map of the entire area I want using

```
ggmap(get_map(location = c(lon=-111.9, lat= 40.7), zoom = 9))
```

Attached is a picture of what I want.

[image: Map of Wasatch Front Communities]

Comment: Here's a nice package and tutorial which should prove helpful: https://arilamstein.com/open-source/choroplethrzip__trashed/creating-zip-code-choropleths-choroplethrzip/

Comment: JasonAizkalns : I saw this link when searching for help. The problem with this was that you needed Region and Value. I am unsure how to get these values/region #s that correspond with the zip code.

Comment: You need a shapefile of zip codes. You can get one using the `tigris` package

Comment: Thanks, I have    zctas_utah<-zctas(cb=TRUE, state = 'Utah')     and I see that      zctas_utah$ZCTA5CE10      would be the corresponding zip codes. However, I am unsure on how to map/plot a zip code boundary. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is just a 2 step problem. Step 1: Geocode. Step 2: add data to the map. If it's not solved by tonight I may have time for it then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a decent foundation for this already by having figured out the shapefile and how it matches the zips you want to show. Simple features (`sf`) make this pretty easy, as does the brand new `ggplot2` v3.0.0 which has the `geom_sf` to plot `sf` objects.

I wasn't sure if the names of the different areas (counties?) that you have are important, so I just threw them all into little tibbles and bound that into one tibble, `utah_zips`. `tigris` also added `sf` support, so if you set `class = "sf"`, you get an `sf` object. To keep it simple, I'm just pulling out the columns you need and simplifying one of the names.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tigris)
library(ggmap)

Tooele       <- c('84074','84029')
NEUtahCo     <- c('84003', '84004', '84042', '84062')
NWUtahCounty <- c('84005','84013','84043','84045')
utah_zips <- bind_rows(
  tibble(area = "Tooele", zip = Tooele),
  tibble(area = "NEUtahCo", zip = NEUtahCo),
  tibble(area = "NWUtahCounty", zip = NWUtahCounty)
)

zips_sf <- zctas(cb = T, starts_with = "84", class = "sf") %>%
  select(zip = ZCTA5CE10, geometry)

head(zips_sf)
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 1 field
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -114.0504 ymin: 37.60461 xmax: -109.0485 ymax: 41.79228
#> epsg (SRID):    4269
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs
#>       zip                       geometry
#> 37  84023 MULTIPOLYGON (((-109.5799 4...
#> 270 84631 MULTIPOLYGON (((-112.5315 3...
#> 271 84334 MULTIPOLYGON (((-112.1608 4...
#> 272 84714 MULTIPOLYGON (((-113.93 37....
#> 705 84728 MULTIPOLYGON (((-114.0495 3...
#> 706 84083 MULTIPOLYGON (((-114.0437 4...
```

Then you can filter the `sf` for just the zips you need—since there's other information (the county names), you can use a join to get everything in one `sf` data frame:

```r
utah_sf <- zips_sf %>%
  inner_join(utah_zips, by = "zip")
head(utah_sf)
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 2 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -113.1234 ymin: 40.21758 xmax: -111.5677 ymax: 40.87196
#> epsg (SRID):    4269
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs
#>     zip         area                       geometry
#> 1 84029       Tooele MULTIPOLYGON (((-112.6292 4...
#> 2 84003     NEUtahCo MULTIPOLYGON (((-111.8497 4...
#> 3 84074       Tooele MULTIPOLYGON (((-112.4191 4...
#> 4 84004     NEUtahCo MULTIPOLYGON (((-111.8223 4...
#> 5 84062     NEUtahCo MULTIPOLYGON (((-111.7734 4...
#> 6 84013 NWUtahCounty MULTIPOLYGON (((-112.1564 4...
```

You already have your basemap figured out, and since `ggmap` makes `ggplot` objects, you can just add on a `geom_sf` layer. The tricks are just to make sure you declare the data you're using, set it to *not* inherit the aes from `ggmap`, and turn off the graticules in `coord_sf`.

```r
basemap <- get_map(location = c(lon=-111.9, lat= 40.7), zoom = 9)

ggmap(basemap) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = zip), data = utah_sf, inherit.aes = F, size = 0, alpha = 0.6) +
  coord_sf(ndiscr = F) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

You might want to adjust the position of the basemap, since it cuts off one of the zips. One way is to use `st_bbox` to get the bounding box of `utah_sf`, then use that to get the basemap.

Comment: This worked! The only issue I have now is how to have the community names pasted on top of the related colored area. Later instead of community name I will want to have different statistics too, so if there is a general way to keep the same map, but change the displayed number/name that would be really helpful.

Comment: Putting text labels at the centroids of shapes and scaling fill based on data are both doable and very straightforward with `sf`, but I think those should each be their own questions separate from this one just to keep a good separation of concerns.